# $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ by $f(x) = (x-1)^2$, what is $f^{-1}( [0,1] )$?

Tags: functions, inverse, inverse-function

> $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ by $f(x) = (x-1)^2$, what is $f^{-1}( [0,1] )$?

How would you go about solving the inverse $f^{-1}([0,1])$?

If I took the inverse of the function itself it would be: $\pm\sqrt{x} +1$

The solution for it is $[0,2]$ but after plugging the numbers in, I'm not sure how that is the case.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/)

Comment: What is $f([0,2])$?

Comment: The inverse doesn't exist as the function is many to one and into.

Comment: @Gary f^-1 ([0,1]) = [0,2] apparently.

Comment: The image of [2,3] under f([2,3]) = [1,4]

Comment: @kyotokohi I asked you to tell me what is the image of the set $[0,2]$ under $f$, i.e., what set is $f([0,2])$?

Comment: It's important to realize that $f^{-1}$ in this case does not refer to the inverse *function* which does not exist because $f$ is not injective.  Instead $f^{-1}(X)$ is what is called the "preimage" of $X$ and is defined as the set of elements that are mapped to $X$.  Or $f^{-1}([0,1])= \{x\in \mathbb R| f(x) \in [0,1]\}$.  So to solve it youd find the solution set of $0 \le (x-1)^2 \le 1$.  Can't you figure this.  Hint  $0\le a \le M^2 \le b \iff 0\le \sqrt a \le |M| \le \sqrt b$.  (It is also important to remember that $\sqrt W$ is *defined* to be $\ge 0$.  Thus $x^2=M$ means $|x|=\sqrt M$)

Comment: ... so $w \in f^{-1}([0,1]) \iff 0\le (w-1)^2 \le 1 \iff 0 \le |w-1| \le 1$. Can you finish?

Answer (score 2):

$x\in f^{-1}[0,1]\iff f(x)\in [0,1]$

$\iff (x-1)^2\in [0,1]\iff 0\le (x-1)^2\le 1 $

$\iff 0\le |x-1|\le 1\iff |x-1|\le 1$

$\iff 0\le x\le 2\iff x\in [0,2] .$